# notifyAll() not working , How to notifyAll all thread in socket programming

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

all thread can wait , but notify 1 thread only(last thread). How to notifyAll all thread?

```
public class Server {   
static Socket clientSocket;
static int count = 0 ;
static boolean listeningSocket = true;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(2343);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 2343");
    }

    while(listeningSocket){
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

        count++ ;
        Serverrun myThread[] = new Serverrun[3];
        myThread[count-1] = new Serverrun(clientSocket); 
        myThread[count-1].start();
        if(count>=3){
            listeningSocket = false;            
        }
    }
    serverSocket.close();       
}
```

}

```
public class Serverrun extends Thread{

Socket clientSocket;

public Serverrun(Socket clientSocket) {

    this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
}

public void run(){

System.out.println("abc");
String clientSentence;
String cap_Sentence;
String rd1,rd2;

try {
    BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    DataOutputStream outToClient2 = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    outToClient2.writeBytes("User Login:"+'\n');        
    clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();       
    System.out.println(" " +clientSentence+ "  : login");

} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("error");
}

    Server s = new Server();
    receivebj(s.listeningSocket);

    Game g = new Game();
    rd1=g.randomNum();
    rd2=g.randomNum();
    DataOutputStream outToClient;
    try {
        outToClient = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        outToClient.writeBytes(rd1+" "+rd2+'\n');
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

synchronized void receivebj(boolean listeningSocket){

        if(listeningSocket!=false){
            try {

                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("work receivebj");
        notifyAll();

}
```

}

I have 3 client 
**Result client1 and client2 not terminated :**

User Login:ant

User Login:bird

**But client3 terminated :**

User Login:cat

Number of card:9 Q

---

Additional
Class Game

```
public class Game { 

String randomNum() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String rd1,rd2;
    String[] names;
    names = new String[12];
    names[0] = "A";
    names[1] = "2";
    names[2] = "3";
    names[3] = "4";
    names[4] = "5";
    names[5] = "6";
    names[6] = "7";
    names[7] = "8";
    names[8] = "9";
    names[9] = "J";
    names[10] = "Q";
    names[11] = "K";
    int num = (int) (Math.random()*12);
    //System.out.println("Number:"+names[num]);
    return names[num];
}
}
```

Class Client

```
class Client {
public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
    String sentence;
    String modifiedSentence1,modifiedSentence2;


    BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost",2343);
    DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    modifiedSentence1 = inFromServer.readLine();
    System.out.println(modifiedSentence1);
    sentence = inFromUser.readLine();       
    outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + '\n');

    modifiedSentence2 = inFromServer.readLine();
    System.out.println("Number of card:"+ modifiedSentence2);
    clientSocket.close();

}
}
```

Result Server:

```
abc
 ant  : login
abc
 bird  : login
abc
 cat  : login
work receivebj method
```

Comment: Dont write code like this. When you get an exception, log the exception, not some futile message of your own devising; and code that depends on the success of code in a prior `try` block should be inside the same `try` block.

Answer (score 2):

Your multi-threading is badly mangled. It seems you have misunderstood the concept of `wait()` and `notifyAll()`. These are not a messaging system that sends messages between different objects.

In `Serverrun` you have `receivebj` that does `wait()`, **while synchronized on itself**. But then you have no code that will actually wake it it up with a `notifyAll()` **on that object**.

So for every `Serverrun`, you just hang its thread, and never wake it up. This cannot work. You need to have a **common object** that your `Serverrun` instances do a `wait()` on.

I suggest going back to basics and read up on multi-threading and concurrency some more, especially [**synchronization**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html), because your error is that you are misusing that.